# React GridList w/ Modal Images

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Well, how to start, hi!

I'm creating some Slider with images using Material-UI GridList, and I want those images to be opened in a modal way, just to see them clearly.

I will put the code, and then explain.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import tileData from './../../utils/tileData'
import useStylesForSlider from './../../hooks/useStylesForSlider'
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList'

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50
  const left = 50

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleModal() {
  // I have this in another folder, i will put the other ones too, i'm just starting
  const classesRoot = useStylesForSlider()
  const classes = useStyles();
  // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const body = (
    <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
      
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classesRoot.root}>
      <GridList className={classesRoot.gridList} cols={2.5}>
        {tileData.map((tile) => (<img src={tile.img} alt={tile.img} onClick={handleOpen} key={tile.img}/>))}
      </GridList>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}>
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have in "tileData" an array with the images, and I map them into a  tag just to put them in the slider (GridList). It works well. Now, i want to click some img, and then open it in modal window. I click it, and the modal opens, but now comes my question, how do I put the image I clicked somewhere in the "body" constant, or how do I do to do it well. I don't know if i'm explaining well, but I expect to have some good advices, i'm pretty new in React world

Answer (score 1):

You could create a state for the current chosen image index (or a unique id) of your tileData array and then load the image in the body by its index (or id). Here is an example:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import tileData from './../../utils/tileData'
import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`
  };
}


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleModal() {
  // I have this in another folder, i will put the other ones too, i'm just starting
  //const classesRoot = useStylesForSlider();
  const classes = useStyles();
  // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const [currentIdx, setCurrentIdx] = useState(null); // add a state for the current index

  const handleOpen = (idx) => {
    setCurrentIdx(idx); // set new current index
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setCurrentIdx(null); // reset current index
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const body = (
    <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
      {tileData[currentIdx] && (
        <img src={tileData[currentIdx].img} alt={tileData[currentIdx].img} />
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <GridList cols={2.5}>
        {tileData.map((tile, idx) => (
          <img
            src={tile.img}
            alt={tile.img}
            onClick={() => handleOpen(idx)}
            key={tile.img}
          />
        ))}
      </GridList>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Live Demo

[image: Edit funny-sea-kxveu]